# Button Names are not showing in App Bar whereas the Title google Maps is visible

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

Actually not an error but buttons "Origin" and "DEST" are not showing in Appbar whereas the title is visible. Kindly help out with this. I am using google api to integrate Google Maps in my app maps are somehow successfully integrated but these two text buttons are not showing in the app bar.These two buttons are also having some longitude and latitude that refers to some location.

```
 runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Google Maps',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: MapScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  static const _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.773972, -122.431297),
    zoom: 11.5,
  );

  GoogleMapController _googleMapController;
  Marker _origin;
  Marker _destination;
  Directions _info;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _googleMapController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        title: const Text('Google Maps'),
        actions: [
          if (_origin != null)
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => _googleMapController.animateCamera(
                CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                  CameraPosition(
                    target: _origin.position,
                    zoom: 14.5,
                    tilt: 50.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                'ORIGIN',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.green,
              ),),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.green,
                // textStyle: TextStyle(
                // ),
              ),
            ),
          if (_destination != null)
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => _googleMapController.animateCamera(
                CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                  CameraPosition(
                    target: _destination.position,
                    zoom: 14.5,
                    tilt: 50.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                'DEST',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
               primary: Colors.blue,
              //   style: TextStyle(
              //
              //     //color: Colors.black,
              //   ),
              ),

            ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: `_origin` got null that's why not showing and also for `_destination`

Comment: If you have values for _origin and _destination, buttons "Origin" and "DEST" will be shown.